# Debugging infinite Sum in Haskell

Tags: debugging, testing, haskell, monoids, applicative

Say I have a function (it doesn't have any practical application, just an academic interest, thus weird way to write it, with monoids, applicative functors and fixpoint combinators)

```
f :: Num a => a -> Sum a
f = fix ((<>) <$> Sum <*>)
```

It typechecks, but I can't be sure it does what it is expected to do before I can test it.

How would one go about testing and/or debugging it? I mean something like seeing the result after several iterations like it is possible with `take 10 [1..]`.

I know a little about simple debugging facilities of `ghci` like `:break` and `:step`, but it steps into non-terminating calculation so I can't inspect anything (it's even problematic to `^C` it). And I can't figure how to use `trace` from `Debug` module in this function either.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you easily see what it does if you expand it to `f = fix (\g -> \x -> Sum x <> g x)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package `ChasingBottoms` with its [`approxShow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ChasingBottoms/1.3.0.5/doc/html/Test-ChasingBottoms-ApproxShow.html) can help you explore partially evaluated values:

```
$ cabal install ChasingBottoms
$ ghci
> import Test.ChasingBottoms.ApproxShow
> import Data.Function
> approxShow 10 (fix (1:))
"[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _"
```

However, here we can’t use it directly: summation over `Integer`s is *strict*, unlike `(:)` which is used to build a list. Therefore another type should be used.

First, some imports (we also need to be able to derive `Data`, so that `approxShow` could be used to show our custom type):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Function
import Control.Applicative
import Test.ChasingBottoms.ApproxShow
```

The type itself (very basic), and its `Num` instance:

```
data S = N Integer | S :+ S
  deriving (Typeable, Data)

instance Num S where
  (+) = (:+)
  fromInteger = N
  --other operations do not need to be implemented
```

Finally, the function:

```
f :: S -> Sum S
f = fix ((<>) <$> Sum <*>)
```

And here is how we can see what `f` is doing with, say, a common number such as 1:

```
*Main> approxShow 5 (getSum (f 1))
"(N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N _) :+ (_ :+ _))))"
```

Of course, it may be more interesting to watch the evolution:

```
*Main> Control.Monad.forM_ [0..7] $ \i -> putStrLn $ approxShow i (getSum (f 1))
_
_ :+ _
(N _) :+ (_ :+ _)
(N 1) :+ ((N _) :+ (_ :+ _))
(N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N _) :+ (_ :+ _)))
(N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N _) :+ (_ :+ _))))
(N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N _) :+ (_ :+ _)))))
(N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N 1) :+ ((N _) :+ (_ :+ _))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't seem to be able to apply it as is to my function though: `approxShow 5 (f 1)` results in `No instance for (Data.Data.Data (Sum Integer))`. And doing `approxShow 10 (getSum (f 1))` does not terminate either.

Comment: @dmedvinsky: sorry, my bad (to be honest, I’ve never heard about `Sum` before and thought that it was some custom type, so I hadn’t bothered myself to check). Answer updated.

Comment: It’s quite interesting that neither `hat` nor `vacuum` were able to help me. At least, I couldn’t find an easy way to accomplish the task while keeping to `Integer`s.